# Am i doing a good job? I seem to have a lot of errors

Tags: c

```
int main() {
double num1, num2;
char f1;
printf("What to Count:");
scanf_s("%f", &num1);
scanf_s("%c", &f1);
scanf_s("%f=", &num2);

if (f1 = "+") {
    printf("%lf\n", num1 + num2);
}
else if (f1 = "-") {
    printf("%lf\n", num2 - num2);
}
else if (f1 = "*") {
    printf("%lf\n", num1 * num2);
}
else if (f1 = "/") {
    printf("%.2f\n", num1 / num2);
}
else if (f1 = "%") {
    printf("%lf\n", num1 % num2);
}
else if (f1 = "#") {
    printf("%lf\n", num1 ^ num2);
}
else {
    printf("Invalid!\n");
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

mvs said "a value of type "const char* " cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char"
"expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always include complete and exact copies of error messages into the question. Inser as formatted text, no screenshots. That should indicate what code is related to the message.

Comment: There are no `#include`s and you're using weird `scanf_s` functions that don't exist on all platforms and that may be poorly implemented on some platforms. And `f1 = "+"` should be `f1 == "+"`, but even that is wrong, comparing strings in C cannot be done like that. And you're not providing the error log in the question. So, no you're not doing a good job. ANd what is mvs

Comment: And what is mvs?

Comment: Use `==` to compare, `=` is for assignment. Character literals are put in single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: @Jabberwocky its Microsft Visual Studio

Comment: strcmp should be used for comparing

Comment: @Kelsey `f1` is a `char`, not a string, so you can't use `strcmp()`.

Comment: @Barmar yes that is true, OP would have to convert it to string first.
Since they're two characters though, wouldn't == work just fine to compare the two characters because it's comparing the underlying binary values of them?

Comment: @Varick well, then [edit] the question and make that cleat in the question itself.

Comment: @Kelsey if the OP creates a string containing that character and a nul-byte, they could still not use `==` to compare as this is not how strings are compare. That would compare the addresses, not the content.

Comment: @Kelsey No, because the value of a string literal is its address, not the underlying character.

Comment: but OP isn't using a string literal, they're using individual characters like char f1, and characters in C are stored as numbers so == comparisons should work fine, like described here:
https://www.delftstack.com/howto/c/compare-char-in-c/

Comment: A char value is stored as it's ASCII value, so using == to compare should be valid.  OP isn't using a pointer, so I don't understand what you mean saying that char c would store the address instead of the value.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. The OP has single characters and hence uses `==` (or tries to use it) but unfortunately provides one parameter of wrong type. Generally `==` is correct here. If the OP converts to a string as you suggested above that would require an array and `==` would compare addresses. Therefore they should not convert to string

Comment: @Gerhardh right missed that, but then `"+"` should be `'+'`.

Comment: @Kelsey sure. That was the type mismatch in the error message.

Comment: @Kelsey, probably the OP *means* to use characters (technically, integer character constants), but in fact, they are indeed using string literals.  `"+"`, `"-"`, *etc*. are examples of the latter.  `'+'` and `'-'` would be examples of the former.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get way more compiler warnings:

- `scanf_s("%f", &num1);` here you have a parameter type mismatch. For `double` you need `%lf`. 
  Fun fact: For `printf("%lf\n", num1 + num2);` you don't need the extra `l` as `float` parameters are passed as `double` anyway.
- Same for `scanf_s("%f=", &num2);`. In this call you also require the user to enter `=` after the number.
- `scanf_s("%c", &f1);` The `scanf_s` function requires an extra argument for `%c` format specifier: *a value of type `rsize_t` indicating the size of the receiving array*
- `if (f1 = "+")` This is an assignment instead of a comparison. Use `==` instead.
- That is also wrong type. `"+"` is a string while you only want to compare a character. That would be `'+'`.
- As Jabberwocky pointed out, you are using all kind of functions without including the required headers. Don't do this.
- `printf("%lf\n", num1 ^ num2);` What is this expression supposed to do? Bitwise `XOR` operator (`^`) is not allowed to be used with `double` values.
- Same with `printf("%lf\n", num1 % num2);` The module operator mustn't be used with `double` values.

Additionally, you should always check return value of `scanf` and related function. Otherwise how would you know about errors?

From the operations that are not valid for `double` I assume you are supposed to use `int` instead.

As you do not use the lengh field of `scanf_s` you couls also use the standard functions instead.
A fixed version of your code could look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(void) {
    int num1, num2;
    char f1;
    printf("What to Count:");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    scanf("%c", &f1);
    scanf("%d=", &num2);

    int result = 0; 
    bool invalid = false;

    if (f1 == '+') {
        result = num1 + num2;
    }
    else if (f1 == '-') {
        result = num1 - num2;
    }
    else if (f1 == '*') {
        result = num1 * num2;
    }
    else if (f1 == '/') {
        result = num1 / num2;
    }
    else if (f1 == '%') {
        result = num1 % num2;
    }
    else if (f1 == '#') {
        result = num1 ^ num2;
    }
    else {
        invalid = true;
    }
 
    if (invalid)
    {
      printf("Invalid!\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%d\n", result);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I moved the printing into one place. That would make it easier to change type of calculations.

Output (in WSL):

```
What to Count:3+5=
8
sh: 1: pause: not found
```

Comment: I don't think there's a newline in the buffer. It looks like the user is expected to type something like `12.1+50=`. So this could be a single `scanf("%lf %c%lf=", &num1, &f1, &num2);`

Comment: `scanf_s("%c", &f1);` is missing a **size** argument.

Comment: I don't see why it is needed for `%c` as well as `%s` and `%[]`.

Answer (score 0):

***Confusing assignment and equality operator:***

Single *'='* is used for assigning a value. For example char a = 5;

This assigns a value of 5 to the character variable a.

Double *'=='* is used for comparison, or checking equality. For example in this case, you have used single *'='* in the conditions, which as you now know is an assignment operator. Replace it with a *'=='*.

***Not including the header files:***

The functions like printf and scanf are predefined in the header file *<stdio.h>*. Without including this, your compiler wouldn't recognize what print and scanf means.

***Not checking input validity:***

When prompting the user for input, always check the return value of scanf. Consider your users stupid, or even hostile who wants to find a way to crash your program. What if I were to enter 'asdf' when you asked for a character and vice versa? Scanf is a powerful function, but it was meant for parsing, not getting input as such.

***Confusing *''* and *" "*:***

*' '* is for a char variable, whereas *" "* is for a string variable. You've declared f1 as a character variable after main, not a string variable.

***Indentation:***

The curly braces are not in their right places. And you may as well omit them when the conditions only contain a single line of code.

***Format specifier for double variable:***

The format specifier for a double variable in the scanf statement is *%lf*, whereas a *%f* is used while printing.

You've also included a *'='* operator in the third scanf statement. That could also render the program to work improperly.